# How to pass php variable into html syntax class name?

Tags: php, html

How to pass php variable in html syntax,
below code was wrong....

```
<div class="lid <?=$row["class_name"]?>">
     text
</div>
```

Comment: This syntax will only work if you are running php 5.3 or if you have short tags enabled.

Comment: Don't forget your semicolon

Comment: @helloworld You don't need a semicolon.

Comment: I was wrong it was 5.4 that made this syntax work without short tags

Comment: so if php 5.4 this syntax will be work?

Comment: @user1575921 See my answer below to see all of the ways that it can be made to work... but php 5.4.0 is when it was made standard equipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php):

> echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.

To enable this syntax you can do one of the following

- set `short_open_tag = 1` in your php.ini file
- add `php_value short_open_tag 1` in your .htaccess file

If neither of these are available you will have to use a full php flag with an echo

```
<?php echo $row['class_name']; ?>
```

Comment: @DevZer0 We seem to have the same activity cycle.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<div class="lid <?php echo $row['class_name']; ?>">
```

Short tags only work by default after version PHP 5.4, and you have to enable shorthand tags for versions before that, in the php settings. `<?=?> and <?php echo ?>` are the same thing, with short tags enabled, but without them,  may not be registered as PHP

Comment: @DevZer0 it won't work if it is disabled. This method will work regardless

Comment: I would expand your answer to explain short tags.

Comment: You copied my mistake from comments... it's actually 5.4 where the syntax became standard equipment for php