# printing only values from my DB, not diplaying null values

Tags: php

[image: Here is the result of suggestion]I am rookie to PHP and I want to display the not null values using foreach statement in every row, The code is as follows, Your support will greatly appreciated

```
<?php

       foreach ($customer['Stocks'] as $stock ) { ?>
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $stock['stsymbol']?><td>
          <td><?php echo $stock['noshares']?><td>
          <td><?php echo $stock['purchaseprice']?><td>
          <td><?php echo $stock['datepurchased']?><td>
          <td><?php echo $stock['Original Value']; ?><td>
          <td><?php echo $stock['Current Price'];?><td>
          <td><?php echo $stock['Current Value']?><td>
<?php } // end foreach ?>
```

Comment: that's some great code you got there.

Comment: this question was asked before today by the another person

Comment: How exactly do you want to display data which doesn't exist?

Comment: Just as an FYI, you're missing a </tr> at the end of that loop as well

Comment: see the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692139/how-to-print-not-null-values-on-php)

Comment: There is nothing to be displayed when its `null`

Comment: what do the "null" values currently display with the posted code

Comment: the phrasing of the question is the error.

Comment: how are you getting the data into the array? And show us a var_dump of the array

Comment: re your image, I'd advise using `!=` instead of `!==` unless you know the value and type of data that constitues "null"

Comment: also, don't use `strlen()` because a value of "NULL" would equal `4`, and that compared to 0 would be false

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    foreach ($customer['Stocks'] as $stock ) {
        if( ! empty($stock['stsymbol'])){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $stock['stsymbol']?><td>
            <td><?php echo $stock['noshares']?><td>
            <td><?php echo $stock['purchaseprice']?><td>
            <td><?php echo $stock['datepurchased']?><td>
            <td><?php echo $stock['Original Value']; ?><td>
            <td><?php echo $stock['Current Price'];?><td>
            <td><?php echo $stock['Current Value']?><td>
        </tr>
<?php
        } // end if
    } // end foreach ?>
```

Comment: I think this is quite an advanced solution. This works in this exact situation, but what if you want to add a check on the price, not to see if it is empty, but to show it via `number_format()`? Readability and maintenance of code is just as important as the actual code :)

Comment: @Martijn - I missed your point. If this question had something do with number format, I would have offered a different solution. Why would I try to offer a solution that didn't have anything to do with the question?

Comment: @Pé de Leão, My seeking solution is not diplaying null values, Your solution is displaying me the word "Null" which replaces my all empty values

Comment: @Pé, that is exactly my point, it only works in this situation. One might prefer answers that are easily changeble or maintainable. To add a numberformat option, you would need to rebuidl this whole part. I'm not saying your solution is a bad one (in fact, it add something people might not know!),

Comment: @BolorCh - I don't know what you want to display. Do you want it empty such as `<td>&nbsp<\td>`? Is it just whane it is actually NULL or when it is empty? I don't know what you want, but like I said, you can replace the strinng `'NULL'` with whatever you want.

Comment: @Martijn - This is easily changeable and maintainable. It would be pretty easy to enter number formatting inside the function.

Comment: @Pé de Leão could you see the picture above? There are empty values, I dont want to display it in my web, so I want to display only columns with values by not displaying null (empty which is undefined or cell without value)

Comment: @Bolor: You want the WHOLE column 'Stock Symbol' hidden if ALL the rows are empty? If so, you might want to update your question :P

Comment: @BolorCh - So if the Stock Symbol is empty, you don't want to display the entire row. Is that right? Why didn't you just say that it your question? Your question says " I want to display the null values" which really doesn't make any sense .

Comment: @Pé de Leão exactly, If one row contains null value, i dont want to display whole one.

Comment: @Pé de Leão Sorry for confuse you, I edited it, Thanks

Comment: @BolorCh - I just updated.

Comment: @Pé de Leão you are genious, that is what I want, unfortunaly, I can't vote it up due to my reputation point. It is very useful

Comment: @BolorCh - You're welcome. If if worked for you, you can click on the check mark to the left to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted for you :) That was a very easy solution :P

Answer (score 0):

use the ternary operator to display your "null" value, else an empty string:

```
<?php
    foreach ($customer['Stocks'] as $stock ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo ($stock['stsymbol'] == NULL) ? $stock['stsymbol'] : ''; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ($stock['noshares'] == NULL) ? $stock['noshares'] : ''; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ($stock['purchaseprice'] == NULL) ? $stock['purchaseprice'] : ''; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ($stock['datepurchased'] == NULL) ? $stock['datepurchased'] : ''; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ($stock['Original Value'] == NULL) ? $stock['Original Value'] : ''; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ($stock['Current Price'] == NULL) ? $stock['Current Price'] : ''; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ($stock['Current Value'] == NULL) ? $stock['Current Value'] : ''; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } // end foreach ?>
```

hope you get the idea

Comment: No need for the breakets arround the condition. Try to make code look as simple as possible :) Adding brackets only makes it look more difficult, and adds no difference (*some situations excluded)

Comment: thankyou. this is just my way of representing the condition as it aids my understanding, a bit like `1 + (2 * 3) = 7 not 9`. but I agree it is not needed in this situation.

Comment: what do you get when you echo out a "null" value? a zero, a string saying 'no data', an empty string?? you need to know the VALUE and TYPE of your so-called "null" before you can implement properly any mechanism for catching it

Answer (score 0):

You can walk through the array before like this:

```
foreach($customer['stocks'] as $key => $value) {

    if(empty($value)) {

        $customer['stocks'][$key] = '-';


    }

}
```

Make your display code better readable:

```
foreach ($customer['Stocks'] as $stock ) {

    echo('<tr>
      <td>'.$stock['stsymbol'].'<td>
      <td>'.$stock['noshares'].'<td>
      <td>'.$stock['purchaseprice'].'<td>
      <td>'.$stock['datepurchased'].'<td>
      <td>'.$stock['Original Value'].'<td>
      <td>'.$stock['Current Price'].'<td>
      <td>'.$stock['Current Value'].'<td>
    </tr>');

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<td><?= strlen($stock['stsymbol'])!==0? $stock['stsymbol'] : '-' ?><td>
```

I replaces your echo with this, this is the short method:

```
// These do the same:
<td><?php echo $something; ?></td>
<td><?= $something ?></td>
```

Then in the echo I made an short if/else (ternary) which works like this:

```
if( strlen($var)===0 ){ echo 'true'; } else{ echo 'false'; }
echo strlen($var)===0 )? 'true' : 'false'; 
// (condition) ? (if true) : (if false);
```

instead of the `strlen($var)!==0`, you could also do `isset($var)`, of `$var===NULL`

Comment: short tags are now disabled.

Comment: Yes I asked it before, but that post did not displayed my foreach loop, so I got the solutions that could not solve the problem, After I noticed that I am posting it again

Comment: @DevZer0: What do you mean?

Comment: its the same solutions as before...just done iteratively

Comment: @Martijn `<?=` short tags. use `<?php echo`

Comment: @DevZer0 as of 5.4 short echo tags are standard equipment in php. see documentation for `echo`

Comment: @Orangepill wasn't there a question this morning about short-tags being disabled after 5.4

Comment: @DevZer0 [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690475/how-to-pass-php-variable-into-html-syntax-class-name/17690567#17690567)